# MAAS on Ubuntu 14.04 comissioning scripts fail

Tags: 14.04, juju, proxy, maas

I have 2 network one private network with private switch and another one connected to internet and a proxy

I have 1 MAAS Server (Ubuntu 14.04) MAAS stable version 1.7

the 3 nodes fail in the same manner while being comissioned.

The UI shows the following scripts as failed:

Error output:

```
failed [3/7] (00-maas-03-install-lldpd, 99-maas-01-wait-for-lldpd, 99-maas-02-capture-lldp)
```

When I look at my log I've got this :

```
00-maas-03-install-lldpd.out

Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libperl5.18 libsensors4 libsnmp-base libsnmp30
Suggested packages:
  lm-sensors snmp-mibs-downloader snmpd
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libperl5.18 libsensors4 libsnmp-base libsnmp30 lldpd
0 upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 1144 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4566 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/ trusty/main libsensors4 amd64 1:3.3.4-2ubuntu1
  Could not connect to spike-dmz.aql.fr:3128 (192.168.194.50), connection timed out
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/ trusty/main libperl5.18 amd64 5.18.2-2ubuntu1
  Unable to connect to spike-dmz.aql.fr:3128:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/ trusty/main libsnmp-base all 5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3
  Unable to connect to spike-dmz.aql.fr:3128:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/ trusty/main libsnmp30 amd64 5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3
  Unable to connect to spike-dmz.aql.fr:3128:
Err http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/ trusty/universe lldpd amd64 0.7.7-1
  Unable to connect to spike-dmz.aql.fr:3128:

00-maas-03-install-lldpd.err

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/pool/main/l/lm-sensors/libsensors4_3.3.4-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  
Could not connect to spike-dmz.aql.fr:3128 (192.168.194.50), connection timed out

E: Failed to fetch    http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/pool/main/p/perl/libperl5.18_5.18.2-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb  
Unable to connect to spike-dmz.aql.fr:3128:

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-snmp/libsnmp-base_5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3_all.deb  
Unable to connect to spike-dmz.aql.fr:3128:

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/pool/main/n/net-snmp/libsnmp30_5.7.2~dfsg-8.1ubuntu3_amd64.deb  
Unable to connect to spike-dmz.aql.fr:3128:

E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com//ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lldpd/lldpd_0.7.7-1_amd64.deb  
Unable to connect to spike-dmz.aql.fr:3128:

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/user_data.sh.jg10Bw/commissioning.d/00-maas-03-install-lldpd", line 65, in <module>
    lldpd_install(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/user_data.sh.jg10Bw/commissioning.d/00-maas-03-install-lldpd", line 49, in lldpd_install
    check_call(("apt-get", "install", "--yes", "lldpd"))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '(u'apt-get', u'install', u'--yes', u'lldpd')' 
returned non-zero exit status 100


99-maas-01-wait-for-lldpd.err

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/user_data.sh.jg10Bw/commissioning.d/99-maas-01-wait-for-lldpd", line 32, in <module>
    lldpd_wait(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/tmp/user_data.sh.jg10Bw/commissioning.d/99-maas-01-wait-for-lldpd", line 23, in lldpd_wait
    time_ref = getmtime(reference_file)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py", line 54, in getmtime
    return os.stat(filename).st_mtime
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/run/lldpd.socket'
```

it look like I've got a problem with my proxy or not ?
Seems this is something trivial with someone with more experience in MAAS. Any help is highly appreciated. IT'S IMPORTANT please

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was a dnssec issue.

Look at this and see if this helps:

> I am able to get rid of the message by commenting the
>   dnssec-validation auto; and adding dnssec-enable no; dnssec-validation
>   no; below it. On Ubuntu/Debian, the named.conf is located in
>   /etc/bind/named.conf.options file.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342003/ns-got-insecure-response-parent-indicates-it-should-be-secure/14923549#14923549